# ActivePivot: Find the CURRENT MEMORY SIZE?

Tags: activepivot

Find the CURRENT MEMORY SIZE ?

Does Active Pivot cube expose the current memory size on the cube ? or
Is it possible to find the current Date's memory Size ?

EXample: Total used Size = 400Gb
         CobDate = 2014040 , Total used Size = 200GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large data structures of ActivePivot (datastore, aggregates, primary index and bitmap index) are allocated in large continuous chunks, they're in general not split by date or any other member and you cannot distinguish.

But that being said, there are many ways to get the total memory usage or your ActivePivot solution (jvisualvm, jconsole, the Quartet FS health check agent...). Then use your favorite frontend to make a simple contributors.COUNT query along your date dimension. That will give you the number of records for each date, and the total number of records, enough to compute an estimate for the memory usage of each date.